# Pointer to member function for as argument for global function

Tags: c++

There is such code:

```
void foo(void (*fun_ptr)()){

}

class B{
public:
    B(){
        foo(some_fun);
    }
    void some_fun(){}
};
```

Compilation error:

```
error: argument of type ‘void (B::)()’ does not match ‘void (*)()’
```

How to point to member function in this case? I cannot change declaration of function foo, only class B!

Comment: Then you can't point to the non-static member.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `B::some_fun()` as `static` as there is an implicit `this` pointer passed as an argument to member functions. Note that making `B::some_fun()` static prevents access to non-public non-static members of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

This a FAQ in it's own right.

There is no other solution than to wrap the member function in a static function and somehow tell it about the object instance to invoke the method on:

```
struct X { void foo(); }

void take_callback(void (*fun_ptr)())
{
      fun_ptr(); // invoke callback
}

//wrap the method

X* instance = 0;

void wrap_memberfun()
{
    if (instance) instance->foo(); // delegate
}

int main()
{
      X x;
      take_callback(&X::foo); // doesn't compile

      // workaround:
      instance = &x;
      take_callback(&wrap_memberfun);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd like it better if you used the same names as OP, just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

some_fun() is a member function and needs an object. Make some_fun() static.

```
static void some_fun() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke non-static member function you need two pointers (function and class instance), so you can't really use pointer to a non-static member where you expect pointer to a function.